# Filter a column matching all of a list of words in R

Tags: r, dataframe, filter

I would like to filter a column in a dataset with >500 rows. The filtering should be done if any of the rows in that column contain all of words from a list of multiple words.

I have used this

```
filter <- (c("stock", "thank", "thanks"))

f1 <- as.data.frame(df[grep(paste0(filter, collapse = "|"), df$comments),])
```

But it filters the dataframe by comments containing at least one of the words not all of them. Is there code that would filter out rows not containing all specified words?

Comment: ```df[Reduce(`&`, lapply(filter, grepl, x = df$comments)),]```

Comment: A skosh faster? `rowSums(!sapply(filter, grepl, x=df$Comments)) == 0`

Comment: RyanGary, I think our comments should resolve this, if not please provide a representative sample of your data using `dput(head(df,10))` (enough rows to show matches and not-matches) and your expected output given that data. BTW, if you're using `grep`, then `"thanks"` is redundant since if `"thanks"` is found then certainly `"thank"` is also found, guaranteed. If you're looking to include word-boundaries or similar, though, that's easy but needs to be accounted for.

Comment: use `df[grepl(paste0('(?=.*\\b', filter,"\\b)",collapse = ''), df$comments),]`